# How to iterate through variables?

Tags: bash

I was using the following in my current script

```
for x in {07..10}
```

Trying to pass the start,end variables to the script using

```
for x in $(seq $1 $2)
```

Since the sequence starts from 07, and 07 is a file name that I want to read, I cant change the variable to 7, as it happens when using the sequence. Can you please point me in the right direction as I don't have much experience with bash.

Comment: thanks for the link, I think it is relevant to my question

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf` to get the number format you want:

```
for (( x=7; x<=10; x++ )); do
   str=$( printf "%02d" "$x" )
   echo filename${str}.txt
done
```

Results look like this:

```
$ for (( x=7; x<=10; x++ )); do str=$( printf "%02d" "$x" ); echo filename${str}.txt; done
filename07.txt
filename08.txt
filename09.txt
filename10.txt
```

Works with variables, too:

```
$ start="07"
$ end="10"
$ for (( x=$start; x<=$end; x++ )); do str=$( printf "%02d" "$x" ); echo filename${str}.txt; done
filename07.txt
filename08.txt
filename09.txt
filename10.txt
```

Comment: Use `printf -v str "%02d" "$x"` to save a fork.

Comment: I have a dishwasher, so I don't mind using an extra fork here and there.

Comment: Being sloppy in your own code is excusable, but in the absence of any indication that the OP would like for the solution to be slightly inefficient, you should probably do your best to avoid unnecessary overhead inside a loop.

Comment: If efficiency is that important, don't use bash.